# Flattening of multidimensional table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I must flattening of multidimensional table in PHP for the following functions to make them more readable. In addition, the effect of this script takes a little time. And here is the code that should work:

```
$data = array(
"one" => "one",
"two" => array(
"three" => "three",
"four" => "four",
),
"five" => "five",
"six" => array(
"seven" => "seven",
"eight" => array(
"nine" => "nine",
"ten" => "ten"
)
)
);

$flat=array();

do{
$newFlat=array();
if(empty($data)) break;
if(empty($flat)) $flat = $data;
$findArray = FALSE;
foreach($flat as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        if(is_string($key)) $newFlat[] = 'Start'.$key;
        foreach($value as $keySec => $valueSec){
            if(is_array($valueSec)){
                if(is_string($keySec)) $newFlat[] = 'Start'.$keySec;
                $newFlat[] = $valueSec;
                if(is_string($keySec)) $newFlat[] = 'End'.$keySec;
                $findArray = TRUE;
            }else{
                $newFlat[$keySec] = $value;
            }
        }
        if(is_string($key)) $newFlat[] = 'End'.$key;
    }else{
        $newFlat[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$flat = $newFlat;
}while($findArray);
print_r($flat);
```

Result is a $flat. May know how to convert this script to exploit less time and less memory? I want the result looks like this:

```
/*
    Result $flat looking like it:
    $flat = [
      'one' => 'one',
          1 => 'Starttwo',
    'three' => 'three',
     'four' => 'four',
          4 => 'Endtwo',
     'five' => 'five,
          6 => 'StartSix',
    'seven' => 'seven',
          8 => 'Starteight',
     'nine' => 'nine',
      'ten' => 'ten',
         11 => 'Endeight',
         12 => 'EndSix'
    ];
    */
```

Ps. Sorry for my reprehensible English. I think that, in spite of this, you will understand me.

Comment: which is the desired output

Comment: What input cases must it deal with? This will only cope with two layers of nesting (PHP arrays are not multidimensional, they are nested). What purpose does the outer loop provide?

Comment: While not possible with this sample array, your use of `empty()` IS going to blow up on you if you ever try this loop on an array with numeric keys: `empty(0)` evaluates to **TRUE**.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is flattening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function flatten_array($data) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $newArray[] = 'Start' . $key;
            $newArray = array_merge($newArray,flatten_array($value));
            $newArray[] = 'End' . $key;
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}

$flat = flatten_array($data);

print_r($flat);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [one] => one
    [0] => Starttwo
    [three] => three
    [four] => four
    [1] => Endtwo
    [five] => five
    [2] => Startsix
    [seven] => seven
    [3] => Starteight
    [nine] => nine
    [ten] => ten
    [4] => Endeight
    [5] => Endsix
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
class array_class
{

  public $data = array();
  public $new_array = array();
  public $value = 1; 
  public $number = "";

  public function __construct($data)
  {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->flatten_array($this->data);
  }

  private function flatten_array($array)
  {
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {            
      if(is_array($value))
      {
        $this->number = $key;
        $this->new_array[$this->value++] = "Start" . $key;
        $this->flatten_array($value);
      }
      else
      {        
        $this->new_array[$key] = $value;
        $this->value++;
      }      
    }         
      $this->new_array[$this->value] = "End" . $this->number;        
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Array
> (
>    [one] => one
>    [2] => Starttwo
>    [three] => three
>    [four] => four
>    [5] => Endtwo
>    [five] => five
>    [6] => Startsix
>    [seven] => seven
>    [8] => Starteight
>    [nine] => nine
>    [ten] => ten
>    [11] => Endeight
> )
> ```